# Finding the function from a Taylor series represented as a summation.

Tags: taylor-expansion

Find a function represented by the Taylor series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\cdot\dfrac{3^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\cdot x^{2k}$.

So, here I first expanded the whole series which gave me $3 - \frac{3^3}{3!}x^2 + \frac{3^5}{5!}x^4 - \frac{3^7}{7!}x^6 + \cdots$. This didn't give me anything conclusive so I tried and rewrote the series as $\frac{1}{x} \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\cdot\dfrac{(3x)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$ but I still don't know how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If the offered answer is *acceptable* to you, please signify that by **accepting** it by hitting the check mark on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key problem-solving tip to apply here is to try and recognize something familiar. If you're fresh out of a calculus 2 course, you may notice that the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{(3x)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$ has a lot in common with the Taylor series expansion of $\sin(x)$.

$$\sin(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$

From this identity, it's easy to see that $\sin(3x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{(3x)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$. Multiplying this series by $\frac{1}{x}$ gives the function in question.

$$\frac{\sin(3x)}{x}=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{(3x)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{3^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}x^{2k}$$

Comment: I get it now. Thank you!